# How to load content to contentplaceholder dynamically in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, contentplaceholder

I have a master page with one contentplaceholder and  the rest of the master page is filled with user control file to define header, navigation etc. I have a side navigation that implements treeview. The treenode is populated with data from database. I want to use the contentplaceholder to show content from different `.aspx` page according to the treenode clicked.

This is a part of master page:

```
<div>
  <div>
   <uc5:lcont ID="lcont1" runat="server"/>
  </div>
  <div>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ccont" runat="server">      
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
  </div>

  <div>
     <uc7:rcont ID="rcont1" runat="server" />
  </div>
```

As you can see the the contentplaceholder is centrally located between two divs. Let me show you the snapshot of it.

[image]

I want to load content from different `.aspx` page to the contentplaceholder denoted by the yellow area. The content needs to be according to the treenode clicked on the right of it.

***What I need is to replace the content inside the contentplace holder by another content within the same page without reloading the whole page.***

Answer (score 1):

What you want here is what exactly the ASP.NET master and content page concept provides. You create a master page, in which you disgn the common layout of the web site. The header, footer, menu etc. The varaible content rendering is delegated to individual content pages, using one or many contentplaceholders in master page.

So now you need to create one or many content pages(.aspx) using "Web form Using Master Page" option in Visual studio. As soon as you create a content page, you get as many  content blocks as you have content placeholders in master page. You need to just render these content blocks, then they will automatically displayed in the respective postion of the master page.

In your treeview, you need to make sure that the tree nodes link to these aspx pages properly. Then as soon as the tree node is clicked, the content will be rendered in the center area as desired.

Comment: Yes but this way i am calling another page that is inheriting the masterpage.What i want is to stick in the same page and get various content in the contentplace holder and at the same time i only need to refresh the contentplace holder only not the whole page.If i call another page by clicking the tree node the new page is render which is not what i want.

Comment: Can we call page in the contentplaceholder? I think its not possible but i am not sure. Is it?

Comment: I think in this case you have two option from me. One is you create all the content in different user controls, instead of aspx, and then dynamically load the respective user control on click of the treeview. Second option could be to use iframes, which can be changed on click treenode, of course the content page should not be actual content page, but normal aspx page with only content part.

Comment: I think you want to use a masterpages and this: http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/  IMHO: the ajaxcontroltoolkit and webforms are the devil. You could also use jquery and make an AJAX call.